# Ansible: how to deal with quotes on variables for win_shell

Tags: powershell, ansible, yaml

This PowerShell script works:

```
$serverInstance = "100.200.300.400,2211"

$database = "myDatabase"

Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $serverInstance -BackupSetName "$database Ansible Deployment Backup" -Database $database -verbose
```

However, when I try to convert this to work in Ansible, it fails because it wants the server instance variable quoted because of the comma for the port.  And it wants the backup set name quoted because of the spaces (I think).

```
- name: Call PowerShell Module to backup database
  win_shell: Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance “{{ serverInstance }}” -BackupSetName “{{ backupSetName }}” -Database {{ database }} -Verbose"
  register: backup_result
```

This syntax gives me this error:

> "cmd": "Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance \"100.200.300.400,2211\"
>   -BackupSetName \"myDatabase Ansible Deployment Backup\" -Database myDatabase -Verbose"
>
> "stderr": "Backup-SqlDatabase : An exception occurred while executing
>   a Transact-SQL \r\nstatement or batch.\r\nAt line:1 char:65\r\n+
>   [Console]::InputEncoding = New-Object Text.UTF8Encoding $false;
>   \r\nBackup-SqlDataba ...\r\n+

I think I want this result for the cmd:

> "cmd": Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance “100.200.300.400,2211”
>   -BackupSetName “myDatabase Ansible Deployment Backup” -Database myDatabase -Verbose

I have read all questions similar to my issue on this site and tried every example. I have tried every combination of single & double quotes, escaping quotes and quote filter to no avail.  I’m sure this is simple.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

UPDATE

---

The serverInstance is an extra variable

serverInstance: "100.200.300.400,2211"

The backupSetName is a fact to concatenate the database extra variable and string.

- set_fact:
  backupSetName: "{{ database }} Ansible Deployment Backup"

I changed the win_shell to the following based on your recommendation of quote filter:

win_shell: Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance {{ serverInstance | quote }} -BackupSetName {{ backupSetName | quote }} -Database {{ database }} -Verbose

This was the result, notice that the backupSetName quoted but the serverInstance did not, is that because it thinks its a list instead of a string?

"cmd": "Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance 100.200.300.400,2211 -BackupSetName 'myDatabase Ansible Deployment Backup' -Database myDatabase -Verbose",

The error was caused because the comma and port # was stripped from the serverInstance variable.

"stderr": "Backup-SqlDatabase : Failed to connect to server 100.200.300.400.\r

We're getting closer, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try {{ serverInstance | quote }} ?

Comment: Please see updated question.  The {{ var | quote }} filter worked but the variable with a comma I think is being parsed as a list.  Not sure how to format that variable so that it is treated as a string.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> win_shell: Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance “{{ serverInstance }}” -BackupSetName “{{ backupSetName }}” -Database {{ database }} -Verbose"
> ```

There's **a definite and a potential problem** with our command:

- The definite problem is that there is a stray `"` at the end of the line.
- A potential problem is that the other quotation marks used on the line are *typographical* ones (`“...”`), not the usual ASCII-range double quotes (`"..."`)

  - *PowerShell* recognizes these *interchangeably* with regular double quotes - but I'm not sure if it affects *Ansible*'s handling of the command.

---

Note: I don't have access to Ansible, so this is *speculative* - do tell us if I got things wrong / you have information to add.

**Potential solutions**:

- Try with ASCII-range double quotes, and the stray `"` at the end removed:

  ```
  win_shell: Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "{{ serverInstance }}" -BackupSetName "{{ backupSetName }}" -Database {{ database }} -Verbose
  ```
- Let a *filter* perform the quoting: Use the [`ansible.windows.quote`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/quote_filter.html) filter with argument `shell='powershell'`:

  ```
  win_shell: Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance {{ serverInstance | ansible.windows.quote(shell='powershell') }} -BackupSetName {{ backupSetName | ansible.windows.quote(shell='powershell') }} -Database {{ database }} -Verbose
  ```

  - Note: This assumes that the filter is smart enough to know that even a string *without spaces* requires quoting if it contains PowerShell *metacharacters* such as `,` (which is the *array-construction operator* in PowerShell).
  - The [`ansible.builtin.quote`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/quote_filter.html) filter that you tried to use does *not* do that: it is meant for *POSIX-compatible* shells such as Bash, not PowerShell.